# Rails for fence?

Tags: fence, cables, railing

We're working on installing a fence in our roof. I want it to have a minimalist look ([something like this without the top rail](https://www.jwlumber.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Atlantis-Railing-Slide9.jpg)), so that it doesn't interfere with the view.

We've already installed the posts in our roof, and now we're searching for the rails. As you can see, the posts can be removed from the base.

Since the posts are removable, the important point is that the rails can also be removed.

We were thinking of using [cable railing](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/c1/d8/29/c1d829c8470ec98514e28b7e6ecc1979--cable-railing-house-.jpg), but I'm thinking if there's anything to replace the cable railing so that it gives it more support.

What type of rail can I install between each post so that the posts are stronger? At the same time, they should be thin and also removable.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: In my area this would not be legal. I understand you do not want to block your view but a child could easily go through that fence. The last elevated deck I built required slats or cables in this case that a 4" ball would not pass through. Check your local building codes.

Comment: If the posts are not strong enough, no railing is going to fix that. So fix that, first. An inadequate roof fence is in some ways worse than no roof fence (with no roof fence, you don't expect to be stopped from going over the edge. With an inadequate roof fence, you hit the fence, or lean on the fence, and over you go....)

Comment: Tempered glass is the other usual "view-retaining" "fence" material, but it comes at a pretty high cost. It is "removable" so long as you don't mind picking up a 10 foot long, 44 inch tall chunk of glass. You might be able to get away with just over 38" tall glass (42 inch top height, less than 4 inch bottom gap.) The wind loading will require your posts to be very well anchored indeed.

Comment: That top rail you do not want, has an important function: it is structurally in compression, to counter the tension of the cables.  Without it, the verticals are cantilevers and you are putting a fairly tremendous sideload on the corner pieces.  You can build for that if you have your heart set on it, but it's much harder.

Comment: That's why I'm asking what type of rails I can put between the posts that are thin and structurally strong.